# What is the best approach to reset state array of object in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-redux, state

I am trying to reset an array of object but I am unable to do it without rewriting the initial value of the state again.
**Initial state**

```
const [state,setState]=useState([
{name:'abc',age:24},
 {name:'xyz',age:20}
])
```

Is there any way that I can reset the state to its initial value without the using the approach that is in the function below.

```
const reset =()=>{
  setState([
   {name:'abc',age:24},
   {name:'xyz',age:20}
  ])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simply create a `const` and store it there

```
const initialState=[
   {name:'abc',age:24},
   {name:'xyz',age:20}
  ]
```

if you want to reset state than
`setState(initialState)`

Answer (score 0):

No there is no built-in way to reset state, but you can improve your version by creating a constant initialState and not duplicating the object:

```
const initialState = [
{name:'abc',age:24},
 {name:'xyz',age:20}
]
...
setState(initialState);
```